# Sigar UnsatisfiedLinkError

Tags: java, debugging, sigar

I'm new to Sigar. I would like to run a simple test to know how I can monitor my system.

I added `sigar-1.6.4` and `log4j` as external libraries, but when I go to run it, I face this error:

`Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: org.hyperic.sigar.Sigar.getCpuInfoList()[Lorg/hyperic/sigar/CpuInfo;
at org.hyperic.sigar.Sigar.getCpuInfoList(Native Method)`

Here is my code:

```
import java.util.Map;
import org.hyperic.sigar.CpuInfo;
import org.hyperic.sigar.FileSystem;
import org.hyperic.sigar.Sigar;
import org.hyperic.sigar.SigarException;

public class Test {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Sigar sigar = new Sigar();
        CpuInfo[] cpuinfo = null;
        try {
        cpuinfo = sigar.getCpuInfoList();
        } catch (SigarException se) {
        se.printStackTrace();
        }

        System.out.println("---------------------");
        System.out.println("Sigar found " + cpuinfo.length + " CPU(s)!");
        System.out.println("---------------------");
    }

}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I understood the problem!
I have to use the following JVM Argument:

```
-Djava.library.path="./lib"
```

in Run Configuration, Arguments tab, VM arguments in eclipse, while the contnet of sigar-bin/lib is in lib folder.

Comment: solved a very strange and annoying problem, thank you!

Comment: I get same error but my problem is not solved yet ??? what is my problem, I use sigar in a web application and libraries are loaded.

Answer (score 5):

Sigar works via JNI.  As such, the appropriate .so or .dll file needs to be in the path specified by the java.library.path property.

Check your sigar distribution - the zip file, I mean. Unzip it and copy the contents of
sigar-bin\lib to a location accessible by your Path, PATH, and LD_LIBRARY_PATH environment variables.  Usually, only one file needs to be accessible per platform.

That should do the trick, if it doesn't, let me know and I'll see what I can do.

Comment: I do what you said, but still the same error, I guess I should set them as vm argument in run configuration in eclipse, but I dont know how to do it. (I mean the command I should write). Can you help please?

Comment: Sounds like from your answer, you eventually understood what I was saying.