# View Java class in JSP page

Tags: java, jsp

Sorry guys I have tried this again through creating class with method inside the main class but it showing this error in jsp page ;

> java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError:
>   org.hyperic.sigar.Sigar.getCpuInfoList()[Lorg/hyperic/sigar/CpuInfo;

I'm not sure if that from the code or Sigar API library sorry again but i need help to get this jsp right

```js
package mydata;

import org.hyperic.sigar.CpuInfo;
import org.hyperic.sigar.Sigar;
import org.hyperic.sigar.SigarException;

public class MyCpu {
private String cpuInfoList;

public String getCpuInfoList() {
 return this.cpuInfoList;
}

public MyCpu() {
 Sigar sigar = new Sigar();
 String output = " ";
 CpuInfo[] cpuInfoList = null;
 try {

  cpuInfoList = sigar.getCpuInfoList();
 } catch (SigarException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
  return;
 }
 for (CpuInfo info : cpuInfoList) {
  output += "Vendor: " + info.getVendor() + "";
 }
 System.out.println(output);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
 MyCpu main = new MyCpu();
}
}

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  <!---JSP--->
  
  <%@page import ="org.hyperic.sigar.Sigar"%>
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>

<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
   "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">

<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>JSP Page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Hello World!</h1>
        <%@page import="mydata.*"%>
        <%
    MyCpu cpu = new MyCpu();
    Sigar sigar = new Sigar();
    out.println(sigar.getCpuInfoList());
%>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: This looks like an error inside the `getCpuInfoList()` method. Can you post the full stacktrace? I'd suspect that a library is missing on the classpath and thus this exception should be thrown at the line `MyCpu cpu = new MyCpu();`

Comment: That is all the code and I have downloaded Sigar library and added to JRE folder, and now I can run it as java application OK BUT I can't run this from JSP .  Thanks Thomas

Comment: The output should be = Vendor + " the CPU vendor name"

Comment: Are you sure that your JSP container uses that JRE? Btw, adding application depencencies to the JRE is not the common way to do that or is that a JVM plugin?

Comment: That is 2 executable jar file (log4j and  sigar) i have added them to libraries

Comment: Did you check this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11612711/sigar-unsatisfiedlinkerror

Comment: If those dependencies are just jars I'd add them to the application's classpath (where exactly depends on the packaging, e.g. for a war it would be WEB-INF/lib) in order to be independent from the JVM there.

Answer (score 0):

You can call java code in JSP using scriplet but it's bad practice to use scriplet in jsp instead use JSTL. Lets move on create one class as mentioned below

```
public class Demo {
    public String output = "";

    public Demo() {
        CpuInfo[] cpuInfoList = null;
        try {
            cpuInfoList = new Sigar().getCpuInfoList();
        } catch (SigarException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        for (CpuInfo info : cpuInfoList) {
            output += info.getVendor() + "\n";
        }
        System.out.println(output);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Demo();
    }
}
```

Change your jsp code to following

```
<%@page import="com.Demo"%>

<!DOCTYPE HTML">
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>JSP Page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <%
            out.println(new Demo().output);
        %>
    </body>
</html>
```

And Add this to classpath `-Djava.library.path="./lib"` in manifest.mf of webapp so finally menifest.mf looks like:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Class-Path: -Djava.library.path="./lib"
```

And ofcourse add `sigar.jar` in lib folder located in WEB_INF.

EDIT:

You should see some kind of below error in your server log:

```
Info: 5 [http-listener-1(5)] DEBUG Sigar  - no sigar-amd64-winnt.dll in java.library.path
org.hyperic.sigar.SigarException: no sigar-amd64-winnt.dll in java.library.path
```

So you have to provide `sigar-amd64-winnt.dll` in lib folder as well.

[image: Lib]

And now you will see output like

[image: output]

Comment: Thank You Naman for your help I will try this and come back to you

Comment: It works mates but also ignoring the main class, this data as you can see is not invoked from the class, it import from class library if I'm right.

Comment: That is very helpful mate, yes it does exactly what supposed to do through calling the method not directly accessing the lib.